# spring boot batch No DataSource specified

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, datasource

I'm trying to configure spring batch but I keep getting `No DataSource specified`.
My Configuration Class:

```
package com.example.demo;

import eu.unicredit.generated.avro.CustomerGorModel;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.PagingQueryProvider;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.builder.JdbcPagingItemReaderBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class Configuration {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean("gorItemReader")
    public ItemReader<String> gorItemReader(DataSource dataSource, @Qualifier("gorQueryProvider") PagingQueryProvider queryProvider) {
        Map<String, Object> parameterValues = new HashMap<>();

        return new JdbcPagingItemReaderBuilder<String>()
                .name("gorItemReader")
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .queryProvider(queryProvider)
                .parameterValues(parameterValues)
                .rowMapper((rs, rowNumber) -> rs.getString("gor_id"))
                .pageSize(1000)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean("gorQueryProvider")
    public SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean gorQueryProvider() {
        SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean provider = new SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean();

        provider.setSelectClause("select gor_id");
        provider.setFromClause("from ur1_bom_customer");
        provider.setWhereClause("where gor_id is not null");
        provider.setSortKey("gor_id");

        return provider;
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.9</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.unicredit</groupId>
            <artifactId>ur1-kafka-avro-lib-be</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@hsomeHost:port/schema
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=passowrd
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No DataSource specified
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:103) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:337) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:395) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.batch.support.DatabaseType.fromMetaData(DatabaseType.java:102) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.getObject(SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.java:159) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.getObject(SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.java:54) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:169) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:101) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1884) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1284) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:345) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    ... 19 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

If I define the data source spring complains for circular dependencies. I've checked in the context and the data source bean is there. Also if I put only this in my configuration class the DataSource is correctly injected:

```
    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
```

Someone knows whats going on here?

Comment: Please add Autowired annotation to the method gorItemReader parameter dataSource.

Comment: same exception @Mar-Z

Comment: Set `DataSource` to `SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean` as well. `provider.setDataSource(dataSource)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the following added to your Configuration class

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
```

and set the data source on SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.

```
SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean provider = new SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean();
provider.setDataSource(dataSource);
```

Terrible, I know!